# How do I tell maven to work with x86_64 packages?

Tags: java, maven, x86, arm, rosetta-2

I want to force maven to use x86_64 packages on my MacBook M1 and run my application through Rosetta 2.

I tried `mvn clean install -Dos.detected.classifier=osx-x86_64` but maven seems to not care about it.

Is there a way to force maven to use packages with a certain architecture?

Comment: Can you show your pom file ... And why native packages are needed? Are you doing OSGi?

Comment: you can configure .m2 directory for x86_64 packages and then configure settings.xml so that maven pulls it offline when you do maven install

Comment: @khmarbaise Firstly it's a way to avoid 'package missing' errors and secondly I need to build and run jars on x86_64 servers.

Comment: @anup What configuration do I need to tell maven to pull x86_64 packages?

Comment: Does unfortunately not answer my question: Why do you need special native packages in Java ?

Comment: Because some packages are not available on arm64 architecture and download sources/recompile it myself is time-consuming. Maybe tell maven to pull x86_64 packages is not the best solution, have you got some suggestions to avoid missing packages on arm64 architecture?

Comment: If you give me more information I might be able to help... What kind of package are not available for arm64 etc. You can't overwrite the os via command line???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `-Dos.detected.classifier=osx-x86_64` parameter is ignored or overloaded, but you can force it.

In your `/Users/yourname/.m2` directory, edit (or create) the `settings.xml` file to create a profile that sets the `os.detected.classifier` property and always enables the profile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>
            apple-silicon
        </activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>apple-silicon</id>
            <properties>
                <os.detected.classifier>osx-x86_64</os.detected.classifier>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Once it's done, just `mvn clean install` and it will download and use `x86_64` packages.